# How to connect my Heroku hosted Node REST services to remote SQL?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, heroku, hosting

**Can anyone please tell me about how to connect REST based services on Heroku to a Linux based Remote SQL?**

I'm new to hosting REST based services. I've created some REST services via Node.js and Express and I'm trying to connect those services with a remote SQL database on my hosting plan on https://ecowebhosting.co.uk.

But it always shows server closed the connection because it requires an IP address to setup a connection between server and heroku.

Comment: Why not use the heroku database?

Comment: Wanted to save some extra cost because data can be really big and I've a unlimited hosting pack that's why.

Comment: So you are hosting on heroku and using ecowebhosting database? Just can the database conn configs (user, password, dbname, db ip and db port) and use them on you express projects

Comment: Already tried it it's not working.